# Laravel: foreach - Error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have this problem, it is complicated to explain so I will try to summarize the easiest to help me,

First in my db I have a field in which I concatenate several numbers, the db adp:

```
ID - Id_fijacion - nr

1  - 1           -  4|5|5|7|....|n-1|n
```

What I am trying to do is to join 3 db, but dividing the chain concatnada(nr: 4|5|5|7|....|n-1|n)

This will do it already.

> Controll:

```
$Metrop  = DB::table('fijacion')->where('tipo','Metro')->join('adp', 'fijacion.id', '=', "adp.id_fijacion")->get();

foreach($Metrop as $Metro){
    $array = explode("|", $Metro->nr);
    $Metro = DB::table('fijacion')->where('tipo','Metro')->join('adp', 'fijacion.id', '=', "adp.id_fijacion")->get();
    $MetroA[] = DB::table('users')
              ->select('*')
              ->whereIn('numero',$array)
              ->where('categoria', '<=', 3)
              ->join('puntos', 'users.numero', '=', "puntos.nr")
              ->orderby('categoria', 'asc')
              ->orderby('total', 'asc')
              ->get();
 }


return view('UJOBBPanel.Designaciones.index',compact('Metro', 'MetroA'));
```

> View:

```
@foreach($Metro as $Metro)

<tr>
<th>{{$Metro->dia}}</th>
<th>{{$Metro->fecha}}</th>
<th>{{$Metro->categoria}}</th>
<th>{{$Metro->hora}}</th>
<th>{{$Metro->cancha}}</th>
<th>{{$Metro->partido}}</th>
<th>@php$array = explode("|", $Metro->nr);$pepe = count($array);@endphp{{ $pepe }}</th>
<th>
<select class="form-control" name="select1" id="arbitro_1">
<option selected="true" disabled="disabled">Selecione 1º Arbitro</option>
<option disabled="disabled">---Internacional---</option>        
@foreach($MetroA as $MetroA)
<option value="{{$MetroA->numero}}">{{$MetroA->nombre}}. {{$MetroA->apellido}}</option>
@endforeach
</select>
</th>
@endforeach
</tr>
@endforeach
```

And I had the following error:

> Property [numero] does not exist on this collection instanc

And this with the 3 variables, can someone give me a hand?

$MetroA:

```
[[{"numero":66,"nombre":"Vivian","apellido":"Garcia"},{"numero":32,"nombre":"Alejandro","apellido":"Sanchez"},{"numero":40,"nombre":"Andr\u00e9s","apellido":"Bartel"},{"numero":53,"nombre":"Gonzalo","apellido":"Salgueiro"},{"numero":29,"nombre":"Nelson","apellido":"Infante"},{"numero":22,"nombre":"Adri\u00e1n","apellido":"Vazquez"},{"numero":77,"nombre":"Valentina","apellido":"Dorrego"},{"numero":59,"nombre":"Carlos","apellido":"Romero"},{"numero":7,"nombre":"H\u00e9ctor","apellido":"Uslenghi"},{"numero":68,"nombre":"Diego","apellido":"Borghini"},{"numero":67,"nombre":"Andr\u00e9s","apellido":"Laulhe"},{"numero":31,"nombre":"Richard","apellido":"Pereira"},{"numero":65,"nombre":"Mart\u00edn","apellido":"Fernandez"},{"numero":35,"nombre":"Crystian","apellido":"Hirigoyen"},{"numero":18,"nombre":"Fabi\u00e1n","apellido":"Martinez"},{"numero":5,"nombre":"Alberto","apellido":"Arenas"},{"numero":46,"nombre":"Pablo","apellido":"Grai\u00f1o"},{"numero":28,"nombre":"Federico","apellido":"Fares"},{"numero":27,"nombre":"Marcelo","apellido":"Collotuzzo"},{"numero":24,"nombre":"Martin","apellido":"Pedreira"},{"numero":50,"nombre":"Alejandro","apellido":"Nadruz"},{"numero":12,"nombre":"Pablo","apellido":"Sosa"},{"numero":13,"nombre":"Enrique","apellido":"Ferreira"},{"numero":61,"nombre":"Andr\u00e9s","apellido":"Haller"},{"numero":37,"nombre":"Diego","apellido":"Ortiz"},{"numero":75,"nombre":"Joaqu\u00edn","apellido":"Silvera"},{"numero":44,"nombre":"Julio","apellido":"Dutra"},{"numero":33,"nombre":"Fernando","apellido":"Pastorino"},{"numero":64,"nombre":"Washington","apellido":"Chamorro"},{"numero":17,"nombre":"Antonio","apellido":"Gomez"},{"numero":20,"nombre":"Ricardo","apellido":"Olivera"},{"numero":52,"nombre":"Martin","apellido":"Rial"},{"numero":86,"nombre":"Mauricio","apellido":"Correa"},{"numero":109,"nombre":"Christian","apellido":"Barreiro"},{"numero":93,"nombre":"Luis","apellido":"Coghlan"},{"numero":104,"nombre":"Alvaro","apellido":"Da Rosa"},{"numero":26,"nombre":"Jorge","apellido":"Araujo"},{"numero":96,"nombre":"Gonzalo","apellido":"Rodriguez"},{"numero":39,"nombre":"Alvaro","apellido":"Aunchayna"},{"numero":51,"nombre":"Andr\u00e9s","apellido":"Olivera"},{"numero":74,"nombre":"Gast\u00f3n","apellido":"Rodriguez"},{"numero":82,"nombre":"Mario","apellido":"A\u00f1orga"},{"numero":58,"nombre":"Iv\u00e1n","apellido":"Tucuna"},{"numero":69,"nombre":"Andr\u00e9s","apellido":"Bustelo"},{"numero":23,"nombre":"Gustavo","apellido":"Cardozo"},{"numero":80,"nombre":"Sebasti\u00e1n","apellido":"Errico"},{"numero":83,"nombre":"Alejandra","apellido":"Godoy"},{"numero":117,"nombre":"Nicol\u00e1s","apellido":"Revetria"},{"numero":47,"nombre":"Marcelo","apellido":"Galli"},{"numero":120,"nombre":"Ignacio","apellido":"Perez"},{"numero":48,"nombre":"Alvaro","apellido":"Labiuza"},{"numero":25,"nombre":"Leonardo","apellido":"Fernandez"}],[{"numero":66,"nombre":"Vivian","apellido":"Garcia"},{"numero":32,"nombre":"Alejandro","apellido":"Sanchez"},{"numero":40,"nombre":"Andr\u00e9s","apellido":"Bartel"},{"numero":53,"nombre":"Gonzalo","apellido":"Salgueiro"},{"numero":29,"nombre":"Nelson","apellido":"Infante"},{"numero":22,"nombre":"Adri\u00e1n","apellido":"Vazquez"},{"numero":77,"nombre":"Valentina","apellido":"Dorrego"},{"numero":59,"nombre":"Carlos","apellido":"Romero"},{"numero":7,"nombre":"H\u00e9ctor","apellido":"Uslenghi"},{"numero":68,"nombre":"Diego","apellido":"Borghini"},{"numero":67,"nombre":"Andr\u00e9s","apellido":"Laulhe"},{"numero":31,"nombre":"Richard","apellido":"Pereira"},{"numero":65,"nombre":"Mart\u00edn","apellido":"Fernandez"},{"numero":35,"nombre":"Crystian","apellido":"Hirigoyen"},{"numero":18,"nombre":"Fabi\u00e1n","apellido":"Martinez"},{"numero":5,"nombre":"Alberto","apellido":"Arenas"},{"numero":46,"nombre":"Pablo","apellido":"Grai\u00f1o"},{"numero":28,"nombre":"Federico","apellido":"Fares"},{"numero":27,"nombre":"Marcelo","apellido":"Collotuzzo"},{"numero":24,"nombre":"Martin","apellido":"Pedreira"},{"numero":50,"nombre":"Alejandro","apellido":"Nadruz"},{"numero":12,"nombre":"Pablo","apellido":"Sosa"},{"numero":13,"nombre":"Enrique","apellido":"Ferreira"},{"numero":61,"nombre":"Andr\u00e9s","apellido":"Haller"},{"numero":37,"nombre":"Diego","apellido":"Ortiz"},{"numero":75,"nombre":"Joaqu\u00edn","apellido":"Silvera"},{"numero":44,"nombre":"Julio","apellido":"Dutra"},{"numero":33,"nombre":"Fernando","apellido":"Pastorino"},{"numero":64,"nombre":"Washington","apellido":"Chamorro"},{"numero":17,"nombre":"Antonio","apellido":"Gomez"},{"numero":20,"nombre":"Ricardo","apellido":"Olivera"},{"numero":52,"nombre":"Martin","apellido":"Rial"},{"numero":26,"nombre":"Jorge","apellido":"Araujo"},{"numero":39,"nombre":"Alvaro","apellido":"Aunchayna"},{"numero":51,"nombre":"Andr\u00e9s","apellido":"Olivera"},{"numero":74,"nombre":"Gast\u00f3n","apellido":"Rodriguez"},{"numero":58,"nombre":"Iv\u00e1n","apellido":"Tucuna"},{"numero":69,"nombre":"Andr\u00e9s","apellido":"Bustelo"},{"numero":23,"nombre":"Gustavo","apellido":"Cardozo"},{"numero":47,"nombre":"Marcelo","apellido":"Galli"},{"numero":48,"nombre":"Alvaro","apellido":"Labiuza"},{"numero":25,"nombre":"Leonardo","apellido":"Fernandez"}],[{"numero":65,"nombre":"Mart\u00edn","apellido":"Fernandez"},{"numero":35,"nombre":"Crystian","apellido":"Hirigoyen"},{"numero":46,"nombre":"Pablo","apellido":"Grai\u00f1o"},{"numero":28,"nombre":"Federico","apellido":"Fares"},{"numero":50,"nombre":"Alejandro","apellido":"Nadruz"},{"numero":61,"nombre":"Andr\u00e9s","apellido":"Haller"},{"numero":75,"nombre":"Joaqu\u00edn","apellido":"Silvera"},{"numero":37,"nombre":"Diego","apellido":"Ortiz"},{"numero":33,"nombre":"Fernando","apellido":"Pastorino"},{"numero":44,"nombre":"Julio","apellido":"Dutra"},{"numero":64,"nombre":"Washington","apellido":"Chamorro"},{"numero":52,"nombre":"Martin","apellido":"Rial"},{"numero":86,"nombre":"Mauricio","apellido":"Correa"},{"numero":109,"nombre":"Christian","apellido":"Barreiro"},{"numero":93,"nombre":"Luis","apellido":"Coghlan"},{"numero":104,"nombre":"Alvaro","apellido":"Da Rosa"},{"numero":26,"nombre":"Jorge","apellido":"Araujo"},{"numero":96,"nombre":"Gonzalo","apellido":"Rodriguez"},{"numero":39,"nombre":"Alvaro","apellido":"Aunchayna"},{"numero":51,"nombre":"Andr\u00e9s","apellido":"Olivera"},{"numero":74,"nombre":"Gast\u00f3n","apellido":"Rodriguez"},{"numero":58,"nombre":"Iv\u00e1n","apellido":"Tucuna"},{"numero":69,"nombre":"Andr\u00e9s","apellido":"Bustelo"},{"numero":82,"nombre":"Mario","apellido":"A\u00f1orga"},{"numero":80,"nombre":"Sebasti\u00e1n","apellido":"Errico"},{"numero":83,"nombre":"Alejandra","apellido":"Godoy"},{"numero":23,"nombre":"Gustavo","apellido":"Cardozo"},{"numero":120,"nombre":"Ignacio","apellido":"Perez"},{"numero":25,"nombre":"Leonardo","apellido":"Fernandez"},{"numero":48,"nombre":"Alvaro","apellido":"Labiuza"},{"numero":117,"nombre":"Nicol\u00e1s","apellido":"Revetria"},{"numero":47,"nombre":"Marcelo","apellido":"Galli"}],[{"numero":66,"nombre":"Vivian","apellido":"Garcia"},{"numero":32,"nombre":"Alejandro","apellido":"Sanchez"},{"numero":40,"nombre":"Andr\u00e9s","apellido":"Bartel"},{"numero":53,"nombre":"Gonzalo","apellido":"Salgueiro"},{"numero":77,"nombre":"Valentina","apellido":"Dorrego"},{"numero":22,"nombre":"Adri\u00e1n","apellido":"Vazquez"},{"numero":29,"nombre":"Nelson","apellido":"Infante"},{"numero":7,"nombre":"H\u00e9ctor","apellido":"Uslenghi"},{"numero":68,"nombre":"Diego","apellido":"Borghini"},{"numero":67,"nombre":"Andr\u00e9s","apellido":"Laulhe"},{"numero":59,"nombre":"Carlos","apellido":"Romero"},{"numero":31,"nombre":"Richard","apellido":"Pereira"},{"numero":65,"nombre":"Mart\u00edn","apellido":"Fernandez"},{"numero":35,"nombre":"Crystian","apellido":"Hirigoyen"},{"numero":18,"nombre":"Fabi\u00e1n","apellido":"Martinez"},{"numero":5,"nombre":"Alberto","apellido":"Arenas"},{"numero":46,"nombre":"Pablo","apellido":"Grai\u00f1o"},{"numero":50,"nombre":"Alejandro","apellido":"Nadruz"},{"numero":12,"nombre":"Pablo","apellido":"Sosa"},{"numero":13,"nombre":"Enrique","apellido":"Ferreira"},{"numero":61,"nombre":"Andr\u00e9s","apellido":"Haller"},{"numero":37,"nombre":"Diego","apellido":"Ortiz"},{"numero":75,"nombre":"Joaqu\u00edn","apellido":"Silvera"},{"numero":44,"nombre":"Julio","apellido":"Dutra"},{"numero":64,"nombre":"Washington","apellido":"Chamorro"},{"numero":17,"nombre":"Antonio","apellido":"Gomez"},{"numero":20,"nombre":"Ricardo","apellido":"Olivera"},{"numero":52,"nombre":"Martin","apellido":"Rial"},{"numero":86,"nombre":"Mauricio","apellido":"Correa"},{"numero":109,"nombre":"Christian","apellido":"Barreiro"},{"numero":96,"nombre":"Gonzalo","apellido":"Rodriguez"},{"numero":26,"nombre":"Jorge","apellido":"Araujo"},{"numero":93,"nombre":"Luis","apellido":"Coghlan"},{"numero":104,"nombre":"Alvaro","apellido":"Da Rosa"},{"numero":39,"nombre":"Alvaro","apellido":"Aunchayna"},{"numero":51,"nombre":"Andr\u00e9s","apellido":"Olivera"},{"numero":74,"nombre":"Gast\u00f3n","apellido":"Rodriguez"},{"numero":82,"nombre":"Mario","apellido":"A\u00f1orga"},{"numero":58,"nombre":"Iv\u00e1n","apellido":"Tucuna"},{"numero":69,"nombre":"Andr\u00e9s","apellido":"Bustelo"},{"numero":80,"nombre":"Sebasti\u00e1n","apellido":"Errico"},{"numero":23,"nombre":"Gustavo","apellido":"Cardozo"},{"numero":83,"nombre":"Alejandra","apellido":"Godoy"},{"numero":117,"nombre":"Nicol\u00e1s","apellido":"Revetria"},{"numero":47,"nombre":"Marcelo","apellido":"Galli"},{"numero":25,"nombre":"Leonardo","apellido":"Fernandez"},{"numero":120,"nombre":"Ignacio","apellido":"Perez"},{"numero":48,"nombre":"Alvaro","apellido":"Labiuza"}],[{"numero":66,"nombre":"Vivian","apellido":"Garcia"},{"numero":32,"nombre":"Alejandro","apellido":"Sanchez"},{"numero":40,"nombre":"Andr\u00e9s","apellido":"Bartel"},{"numero":53,"nombre":"Gonzalo","apellido":"Salgueiro"},{"numero":29,"nombre":"Nelson","apellido":"Infante"},{"numero":22,"nombre":"Adri\u00e1n","apellido":"Vazquez"},{"numero":77,"nombre":"Valentina","apellido":"Dorrego"},{"numero":7,"nombre":"H\u00e9ctor","apellido":"Uslenghi"},{"numero":67,"nombre":"Andr\u00e9s","apellido":"Laulhe"},{"numero":59,"nombre":"Carlos","apellido":"Romero"},{"numero":68,"nombre":"Diego","apellido":"Borghini"},{"numero":31,"nombre":"Richard","apellido":"Pereira"},{"numero":65,"nombre":"Mart\u00edn","apellido":"Fernandez"},{"numero":35,"nombre":"Crystian","apellido":"Hirigoyen"},{"numero":18,"nombre":"Fabi\u00e1n","apellido":"Martinez"},{"numero":5,"nombre":"Alberto","apellido":"Arenas"},{"numero":46,"nombre":"Pablo","apellido":"Grai\u00f1o"},{"numero":28,"nombre":"Federico","apellido":"Fares"},{"numero":27,"nombre":"Marcelo","apellido":"Collotuzzo"},{"numero":24,"nombre":"Martin","apellido":"Pedreira"},{"numero":12,"nombre":"Pablo","apellido":"Sosa"},{"numero":50,"nombre":"Alejandro","apellido":"Nadruz"},{"numero":61,"nombre":"Andr\u00e9s","apellido":"Haller"},{"numero":13,"nombre":"Enrique","apellido":"Ferreira"},{"numero":75,"nombre":"Joaqu\u00edn","apellido":"Silvera"},{"numero":37,"nombre":"Diego","apellido":"Ortiz"},{"numero":44,"nombre":"Julio","apellido":"Dutra"},{"numero":33,"nombre":"Fernando","apellido":"Pastorino"},{"numero":64,"nombre":"Washington","apellido":"Chamorro"},{"numero":17,"nombre":"Antonio","apellido":"Gomez"},{"numero":20,"nombre":"Ricardo","apellido":"Olivera"},{"numero":52,"nombre":"Martin","apellido":"Rial"},{"numero":86,"nombre":"Mauricio","apellido":"Correa"},{"numero":109,"nombre":"Christian","apellido":"Barreiro"},{"numero":93,"nombre":"Luis","apellido":"Coghlan"},{"numero":104,"nombre":"Alvaro","apellido":"Da Rosa"},{"numero":26,"nombre":"Jorge","apellido":"Araujo"},{"numero":96,"nombre":"Gonzalo","apellido":"Rodriguez"},{"numero":39,"nombre":"Alvaro","apellido":"Aunchayna"},{"numero":83,"nombre":"Alejandra","apellido":"Godoy"},{"numero":23,"nombre":"Gustavo","apellido":"Cardozo"},{"numero":47,"nombre":"Marcelo","apellido":"Galli"},{"numero":117,"nombre":"Nicol\u00e1s","apellido":"Revetria"},{"numero":25,"nombre":"Leonardo","apellido":"Fernandez"},{"numero":120,"nombre":"Ignacio","apellido":"Perez"}]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this :

```
@foreach($MetroA as $MetroA)
<option value="{{$MetroA->numero}}">{{$MetroA->nombre}}. {{$MetroA->apellido}}</option>
@endforeach
```

to

```
@foreach($MetroA[0] as $item)
<option value="{{$item->numero}}">{{$item->nombre}}. {{$item->apellido}}</option>
@endforeach
```

Comment: it does not work,
Property [number] does not exist on this collection instance.

Comment: look this is another error: first one was Property [numero] not [number]

Comment: can you show me where the `[number]` which line ? because i don't see any variable called  `number` in your code

Comment: If it has an error with all 3 variables.
[numero] or [nombre] or [apellido]

Comment: es una columna de la db usuario

Comment: can you share the content of `$MetroA` variable

Comment: @AlejandroMuñozSchumacher look at my updated answer use this instead `@foreach($MetroA[0] as $item)`